# Can't debug why app does not show in certain countries

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

We are developing an app in Ionic right now and published through the Play Store.

The current version of the app has been made available in all countries available in the list on the Google Play Console portal, however some users from a specific country are reporting not being able to find it when searching and being told that "not available in your region" when viewing the web listing.

We have tried fixing it by going to the console and making the app available through the whole Store, but that hasn't fixed the problem so far.

We are out of ideas on what to check to figure out what's wrong :(

Comment: What kind of app is it you´ve created? All cummon reasons: Maybe published for all countries, but not "legit" with country rights/age or need to be checked first. Maybe users got a not valid android version - but normaly they got this message (but users are dumb). Check this first. Which Countries are "not available"?

Comment: Ionic app, seems somebody managed to install when viewing the direct listing on web page but couldn't find it when searching the exact name. Didn't show nothing.

Comment: It's such a strange issue but seems since the guy managed to solve it I guess it's not worth bothering anyone with it now, so I'll just mark this as solved... In 2 days when this website allows me to hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve by viewing direct listing instead of going through search.